# Increasing robustness of executing a function every x seconds

Tags: c, loops, timer

I have written some code that tries to call a function (called worker) every x seconds (in this example, I chose 1s as the interval time). The code is a minimal working example that in reality is way more complex than this.

The code works when it is this simple, but I stumble across errors when running the more complex version for a longer period of time. Thus, I want to increase the robustness of this code an would like to get some ideas on how to do that.

Basically, the worker gets some data, processes it an writes it to a file. I open the file during every call to the worker. In the tests, after some time I get an error that the file cannot be opened anymore. In this regard I also noticed that this happens (maybe just by chance) everytime the worker execution time exceeds the interval time. Reason for this is the getter function which pulls data from remote and this can take some time, depending on the network traffic.

I've been thinking of trying a multithreaded approach, but I am not sure if this is worth the hassle. I would be grateful for any pointers on how to do this in a more robust way.

```
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ALARM_INTERVAL_SEC 1
#define ALARM_INTERVAL_USEC 0

static bool running = true;
static struct itimerval alarm_interval;
static struct timeval previous_time;
static uint64_t loop_count = 0;
static FILE* testfile;

static void
signal_handler(int signum)
{
    if (signum == SIGINT || signum == SIGTERM) 
    {
        running = false;
    }
}

static void
worker(int signum)
{
    // Reset the alarm interval
    if(setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &alarm_interval, NULL) < 0)
    {
        perror("Error: setitimer");
        raise(SIGTERM);
        return;
    }

    struct timeval current_time;
    gettimeofday(&current_time, NULL);
    printf("Loop count: %lu\n", loop_count);
    printf("Loop time: %f us\n\n", (current_time.tv_sec - previous_time.tv_sec) * 1e6 +
                           (current_time.tv_usec - previous_time.tv_usec));
    previous_time = current_time;

    // convert time to human-readable format
    char tmbuf[64];
    char buf[64];
    time_t nowtime = current_time.tv_sec;
    struct tm *nowtm = localtime(&nowtime);
    strftime(tmbuf, sizeof(tmbuf), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", nowtm);
    snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%s.%06ld", tmbuf, current_time.tv_usec);

    sleep(0.5);

    // DO STH
    testfile = fopen("testfile.txt", "ab+");
    if(testfile == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: open testfile");
        raise(SIGTERM);
        return;
    }

    fprintf(testfile, "[%s] Loop count: %lu\n", buf, loop_count);

    fclose(testfile);

    loop_count++;
}

int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
    signal(SIGTERM, signal_handler);
    signal(SIGALRM, worker);

    // Set the alarm interval
    alarm_interval.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    alarm_interval.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
    alarm_interval.it_value.tv_sec = ALARM_INTERVAL_SEC;
    alarm_interval.it_value.tv_usec = ALARM_INTERVAL_USEC;

    if(setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &alarm_interval, NULL) < 0)
    {
        perror("Error: setitimer");
        return -1;
    }

    gettimeofday(&previous_time, NULL);

    while(running)
    {
        sleep(1);
    }

    alarm_interval.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
    alarm_interval.it_value.tv_usec = 0;
    if(setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &alarm_interval, NULL) < 0)
    {
        perror("Error: resetting itimer failed");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that the POSIX standard `sleep()` take an integer argument — passing `0.5` gets converted to `0` and there is no sleep duration.

Comment: What is the error you get when you fail to open the file?  Is it `EMFILE` (too many files open in the process) or something else?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Errno returns "Too many open files", I guess that is what you meant.

Comment: There are two closely related errors — with the symbolic names in `<errno.h>` of `ENFILE` and `EMFILE`.  On macOS, the messages are: `ENFILE (23): Too many open files in system` and `EMFILE (24): Too many open files`.  The first is a system-wide limit on the number of files; the second is a per-process limit.  It is more likely that you're hitting the per-process limit.  That, in turn, means you are not closing all the files you open.  If your processing takes too long, you could be running into recursion as a new signal handler takes over when the next signal arrives.

Comment: If you used `sigaction()` instead of `signal()` to set your signal handling, you could block further occurrences of `SIGALRM` while you're processing the current signal.  You'd have to worry about catching up in due course — how would you process two or more seconds worth of data in less than a second.  Once you start to get behind, you're in trouble.  Because you use a single global variable `FILE *testfile`, you lose track of previous opens of the file.  You might be able to check whether `testfile` is NULL or not if you nullify it after closing the file.